# Spring Boot JPA Connection Closed after period of inactivity

Tags: spring, azure, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application that is deployed to Azure.  This application uses JPA to connect to a SQL Server database.   Everything seems to work nicely, until after ~30 minutes of inactivity.  My guess is the database is closing the connection and the spring boot (tomcat) container isn't properly handling this situation.

I'm injecting the datasouce properties via:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

My application.properties are:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx:1433;database=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-interval=0
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandonedTimeout=120
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=34000
spring.datasource.tomcat.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=55000
spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize=4
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive=16
```

However after a period of inactivity i'm getting SQLExceptions:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
```

I'm trying to determine the cause of this.  I'm guesses connection validation isn't working correctly, but as I understand this, the connection should be validate by tomcat before the application is allowed to use it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a warning/debug message, or is it thrown out of the JPA code? Technically the DB server can close the connection at any time, so if the pool detects a stale connection it may log a warning like this. If it happens all the time, you should probably look at the servers idle timeout.

Comment: which version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: Can you show more of your logs ? Are these warnings, errors, debug statements etc ?

Comment: After digging around and turning on the Spring Boot Actuator, I was able to look at the configProps endpoint and found that the tomcat.* properties are not being included into the DataSource.  My question is what is the proper way to include the connection validation properties?

Comment: I changed my properties from spring.datasource.tomcat.* to spring.datasource.* and all my properties got include in the datasource and my problem went away.